# Reducing the size of list of algorithms title

Tags: table-of-contents, algorithms

I have used the report class document that all packages used in the document are as follows:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[top=45mm, bottom=45mm, left=40mm, right=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[textfont={footnotesize},labelfont={bf,small},format=hang,labelsep=quad]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0,.55}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Blue,urlcolor=Blue,citecolor=Blue]{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithms
\chapter{Chapter First}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The generalized global Arnoldi algorithm}
\label{alg1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE Set $\beta=\Arrowvert V\Arrowvert_{F}$, $V_{1}=V/\beta.$
\FOR {$j=1, \ldots, k$}
\STATE $W_{j}=AV_{j}B$
\FOR{$i=1, \ldots, j$}
\STATE $W_{j}=W_{j}-h_{ij}V_{i}$
\ENDFOR
\STATE $h_{j+1, j}=\Arrowvert W_{j}\Arrowvert_{F}.$ If $h_{j+1, j}=0$ then stop.
\STATE $V_{j+1}=W_{j}/h_{j+1, j}.$
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

In order to create the list of algorithms, I apply the following command

```
\listofalgorithms
```

Is there a way to reduce the size of list of algorithms title?

Comment: Sure there is a away to reduce the font size. But to tell which way is applicable to your problem, we need a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: Yes. Of course. I have used the report class document and I apply some packages.

Comment: @ samcarter, I modified my original question.

Comment: Do you also want to reduce the size of `list of figures` or `list of tables`?

Comment: @ Bernard, yes.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest to redefine the command that is responsible for typesetting the header. Put the following commands into your preamble.

```
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\float@listhead[1]%
   {\@ifundefined{chapter}%
      {\def\@tempa{\section*}}%
      {\def\@tempa{\chapter*}}%
    \@tempa
      {\listheaderformat#1\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}%
   }
\newcommand\listheaderformat{}
\makeatother
```

To change the header format globally for all lists, add the line

```
\renewcommand\listheaderformat{\small}
```

to the preamble, right after the definitons above.

To change the header format only for one list, add this line directly before the corresponding list and enclose it in a group.

```
{\renewcommand\listheaderformat{\small}%
 \listofalgorithms
}
```

Here is the code of the original post with the proposed redefinition.

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[top=45mm, bottom=45mm, left=40mm, right=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[textfont={footnotesize},labelfont={bf,small},format=hang,labelsep=quad]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0,.55}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Blue,urlcolor=Blue,citecolor=Blue]{hyperref}
\makeatletter
\renewcommand\float@listhead[1]%
   {\@ifundefined{chapter}%
      {\def\@tempa{\section*}}%
      {\def\@tempa{\chapter*}}%
    \@tempa
      {\listheaderformat#1\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase{#1}}{\MakeUppercase{#1}}}%
   }
\newcommand\listheaderformat{}
\makeatother
\renewcommand\listheaderformat{\small}
\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithms
\chapter{Chapter First}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The generalized global Arnoldi algorithm}
\label{alg1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE Set $\beta=\Arrowvert V\Arrowvert_{F}$, $V_{1}=V/\beta.$
\FOR {$j=1, \ldots, k$}
\STATE $W_{j}=AV_{j}B$
\FOR{$i=1, \ldots, j$}
\STATE $W_{j}=W_{j}-h_{ij}V_{i}$
\ENDFOR
\STATE $h_{j+1, j}=\Arrowvert W_{j}\Arrowvert_{F}.$ If $h_{j+1, j}=0$ then stop.
\STATE $V_{j+1}=W_{j}/h_{j+1, j}.$
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I applied the commands that you have suggested them. But I have got some errors.   For example: ! LaTeX Error: Missing \begin{document}.See the LaTeX manual or LaTeX Companion for explanation.Type H <return> for immediate help.... ...\listheaderformat{\small}\listofalgorithms

Comment: @Farid I have extended my answer by adding your code with the redefinition. It compiles without errors. It seems that you have added `\listofalgorithms` also to the preamble. This command has to go into the main document after `\begin{document}`, where you want the list of figures to appear.

Answer (score 1):

A quick hack: `\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{\small List of Algorithms}` or whatever size you want.

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%% packages %%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{amsthm,amssymb,amsmath,enumerate}
\usepackage{mathrsfs}
\usepackage[cam,a4,center,noinfo]{crop}
\usepackage[top=45mm, bottom=45mm, left=40mm, right=40mm]{geometry}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tocloft}
\usepackage{emptypage}
\usepackage{algorithm}
\usepackage{algorithmic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{framed}
\usepackage[textfont={footnotesize},labelfont={bf,small},format=hang,labelsep=quad]{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage[nottoc,notlof,notlot]{tocbibind}
\usepackage{makeidx}
\makeindex
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{indentfirst}
\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{Blue}{rgb}{0,0,.55}
\usepackage[colorlinks=true,linkcolor=Blue,urlcolor=Blue,citecolor=Blue]{hyperref}

\renewcommand{\listalgorithmname}{\small List of Algorithms}

\begin{document}
\tableofcontents
\listofalgorithms
\chapter{Chapter First}
\begin{algorithm}
\caption{The generalized global Arnoldi algorithm}
\label{alg1}
\begin{algorithmic}[1]
\STATE Set $\beta=\Arrowvert V\Arrowvert_{F}$, $V_{1}=V/\beta.$
\FOR {$j=1, \ldots, k$}
\STATE $W_{j}=AV_{j}B$
\FOR{$i=1, \ldots, j$}
\STATE $W_{j}=W_{j}-h_{ij}V_{i}$
\ENDFOR
\STATE $h_{j+1, j}=\Arrowvert W_{j}\Arrowvert_{F}.$ If $h_{j+1, j}=0$ then stop.
\STATE $V_{j+1}=W_{j}/h_{j+1, j}.$
\ENDFOR
\end{algorithmic}
\end{algorithm}
\end{document}
```

---

**Note:** if the name of the algorithm list is also used anywhere else, like the toc or the page headers, this will also change the font size there - so in this case you definitely want to use a more complex solution.

Comment: If you pack the formatting instructions into `\listalgorithmname`, then they will also be used for the page header (in the `\markboth` command).

Comment: @gernot yes, and they will also destroy the toc. But as the example did not show the obvious packages for pageheaders, I thought it would be worth a try...